# How can I add properties for each element in array of gameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

//[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class InstantiateObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objectsToInstantiate;
    public Terrain terrain;
    public float yOffset = 0.5f;
    public int numberOfObjectsToCreate;
    public bool parent = true;
    public bool randomScale = false;
    public float setRandScaleXMin, setRandScaleXMax;
    public float setTandScaleYMin, setTandScaleYMax;
    public float setTandScaleZMin, setRandScaleZMax;

    private float terrainWidth;
    private float terrainLength;
    private float xTerrainPos;
    private float zTerrainPos;
    private GameObject objInstance;
    private GameObject[] createdObjects;
    private string objname;

    public void Start()
    {
        //Get terrain size
        terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
        terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;

        //Get terrain position
        xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
        zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

        for(int i = 0; i < objectsToInstantiate.Length; i++)
        {
            objname = objectsToInstantiate[i].name;
            MyCustomEditor.TagsAndLayers.AddTag(objname);
        }

        generateObjectOnTerrain();
    }

    public void Update()
    {

    }

    public void DestroyObjects()
    {
        UpdateList(true);

        if (createdObjects != null && createdObjects.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < createdObjects.Length; i++)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(createdObjects[i]);
            }
            createdObjects = new GameObject[0];
        }
    }

    public void generateObjectOnTerrain()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToInstantiate.Length; i++)
        {
            //Generate random x,z,y position on the terrain
            float randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
            float randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);

            float yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));

            //Generate random x,y,z scale on the terrain
            float randScaleX = Random.Range(setRandScaleXMin, setRandScaleXMax);
            float randScaleY = Random.Range(setTandScaleYMin, setTandScaleYMax);
            float randScaleZ = Random.Range(setTandScaleYMax, setRandScaleZMax);

            //Apply Offset if needed
            yVal = yVal + yOffset;

            //Generate the Prefab on the generated position        
            objInstance = Instantiate(objectsToInstantiate[i], new Vector3(randX, yVal, randZ), Quaternion.identity);

            if (randomScale == true)
                objInstance.transform.localScale = new Vector3(randScaleX, randScaleY, randScaleZ);

            if (parent)
                objInstance.transform.parent = this.transform;

            objInstance.tag = objname;
        }

        createdObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(objname);

        if (objname == "Teleportation Booth")
            UpdateList(false);
    }

    private void UpdateList(bool destroy)
    {
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
        var list = go.GetComponent<PatrolOverTerrain>().Targets;
        if (destroy == false)
        {
            list.AddRange(createdObjects);
            go.GetComponent<PatrolOverTerrain>().Targets = list;
        }

        if (destroy == true)
        {
            list.Clear();
            go.GetComponent<PatrolOverTerrain>().Targets.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Instead attaching the script to every gameObject I will want to clone I want to use array of objects.

For example let's say I have in the array 2 objects, now I want in the inspector to have under each element its own properties.
And when I will set the properties as children for each element it will take effect for the specific element only.
[image: Inst]

Instead general properties for all the elements to make this properties from Y Offset until the last Set Rand Scale Z Max to be children for each element.
So i can set the properties per element.

So I can expand each element and see his properties.

Btw: How can I change the random for example that: Set Rand Scale X Min and Set Rand Scale X Min will be on one line and not two lines ? Like:

Set Rand Scale X Min     Max
Set Rand Scale Y Min     Max
Set Rand Scale Z Min     Max

Comment: Not sure I get it but have you tried an array of InstantiateObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good way to do this would be creating custom class and then making array of instances of that class but it require a bit more lines. If you like to read more about this search [ISerializationCallbackReceiver](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html).

Simplest would be probably wrapping your variables in struct like below. You can then "unwrap" them to your classes or not. That depends on what you do want.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class InstantiateObjects : MonoBehaviour {

    public ObjectsToInst[] objectsToInstantiate;

    [Serializable]
    public struct ObjectsToInst
    {
        public GameObject objectToInstantiate;
        public Terrain terrain;
        public float yOffset;
        public int numberOfObjectsToCreate;
        public bool parent;
        public bool randomScale;
        public float setRandScaleXMin, setRandScaleXMax;
        public float setTandScaleYMin, setTandScaleYMax;
        public float setTandScaleZMin, setRandScaleZMax;
    }
}
```